# Does mysql_query commit everything

Tags: php, mysql, commit

I am using mysql extension in php, I know it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, but I have a lot of code allready written with the use of this extension.
It seems to me like mysql_query commits the query, if so it means that it is set to autocomit, How to setup so it does not autocommit.

Comment: If you were using MySQLi, you could do MySQLi::autocommit. If you were using PDO, you could do PDO::beginTransaction. Nobody wants to help keep mysql_* alive.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible using the mysql_* methods, you will need to at least upgrade to mysqli. This can be done with minimal effort because it has procedural style operations similar to mysql.

Comment: Yeah is see that you can just add i, so I will use mysqli

Comment: Converting mysql to mysqli is a little more complicated than just adding i....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old mysql extension doesn't have functions specifically for transaction control, but you can issue SQL statements to do what you want.

You can implicitly turn off autocommit for the duration of one transaction simply by starting a transaction:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
```

As soon as you COMMIT or ROLLBACK, the autocommit mode will return to the default.

```
mysql_query("COMMIT"); // or ROLLBACK
```

You can turn off autocommit for your whole session by setting a session variable:

```
mysql_query("SET autocommit=0");
```

Or change it globally on your MySQL instance so it changes the default for all sessions:

```
mysql_query("SET GLOBAL autocommit=0");
```

Or set it to change the global setting upon MySQL service startup by editing /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
autocommit=0
```

If you use MySQL 5.1, you have to do this slightly differently:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET autocommit=0'
```

You probably already know, but it bears repeating that transactions only mean anything if you're using InnoDB tables.  MyISAM tables don't support transactions, so they're always autocommit regardless of your settings.  Same with several other storage engines, including MEMORY and CSV.